# Does Automatic Downloads on iPhone 6 use cellular data on international roaming?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

Under Automatic Downloads for iTunes & App Stores, there's a setting for downloading app Updates.

Does it use cellular data while on international roaming?

Comment: if you have it set up to `allow` then it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to download app updates over Mobile Data is a user configurable setting. Go to Settings app → iTunes & App Store and turn off **Use Mobile Data**. This will ensure that app updates are not downloaded over mobile data even if it is enabled.

This setting doesn't take into account device roaming status (which itself is configurable under Settings app → Mobile Data).

[image]

Even if **Use Mobile Data** is enabled here, it still needs the Mobile Data itself to be enabled under Settings → Mobile Data.

If you are concerned about using data while roaming, turning off Mobile Data under Settings will ensure that no cellular data usage will happen.

Comment: Thanks so much and when i enter another country how will i enable my mobile to receive or send calls on my own country sim. do i have to change anything on setting

Comment: @WorldWillEnd Seek assistance with your service provider regarding this as only they can answer it. Ask them about how the roaming activation and calling. If you wish to use your phone "without" activating cellular services, simply enable Airplane mode. You can still turn on Wi-Fi and Bluetooth while the phone is in Airplane mode.

Comment: They said it is activated automatically when you ented another country abroad.

Comment: @WorldWillEnd Just keep the mobile data turned off and you will be fine. No need to post different questions with the same overall agenda.